# PHP form submit to different page

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a PHP form submit to different page(submit to page that where selected)

So, what I've tried and it's not working:

```
<form class="notice-success" action="<?php echo $_POST['type'] ?>">

<select name="type" form="submit">
  <option value="a1.php">Page 1 </option>
  <option value="a2.php">Page 2</option>
  <option value="a3.php">Page 3</option>
</select>

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

If selected Page 1, on submitting to go to page a1.php...

Any idea how to get that?

Comment: You need to use JavaScript, because the action takes place in the browser, not on the server.

Comment: the `$_POST['type']` variable will not be set on page load - use javascript to submit the form after getting the value from the select menu

Comment: You could do it differently and post the form, then on the server redirect according to the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using the onsubmit event handler to set the action of the form. Check the developer tools to see the snippet attempting to submit to different urls based on the selection.

```js
var myForm = document.forms[0];
var select = document.forms[0]['type'];

myForm.onsubmit = function() {
  myForm.setAttribute('action', select.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="notice-success">

  <select name="type">
  <option value="a1.php">Page 1 </option>
  <option value="a2.php">Page 2</option>
  <option value="a3.php">Page 3</option>
</select>

  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```